# Matplolib plot in the X axis has the date in format xxxx-xx-xx 00:00:00, how to change to xxxx-xx-xx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, types

I am using JupyterLab and I am trying to make a matplotlib graph, value count (y-axis), and in the x-axis add the year of device introduction as `xxxx-xx-xx 00:00:00`. Interestingly, the column with the data retrieves in the format `xxxx-xx-xx` and the column for data is type: `datetime64[ns]`. I want to make the graph display only `xxxx-xx-xx` (i.e. only show the date and not the time). How can I do this? One alternative I took was to change the datatype from `datetime64[ns]` to string. In this case, the graph shows the date fine (`xxxx-xx-xx`), however, matplotlib also graphs in the x-axis all the `NaT`, which is a larger in value count than any other real date.

```
# I change the data types, I tried to remove the NaT:
ndf_dropped_rows = ndf.dropna()
ndf['opening_date_clean'].value_counts()

# I also tried 
ndf_dropped_rows = ndf.dropna()
ndf['opening_date_clean'].value_counts() #but I get the following table:
NaT           250
1999-01-01     10
2022-01-01      8
1985-01-01      7
1976-01-01      7
             ... 
1996-05-16      1
1996-04-30      1
1996-04-29      1
1996-06-10      1
2022-02-01      1
Name: opening_date_clean, Length: 603, dtype: int64
```

So basically the `NaT` are still there.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib provides 3 date formatters: `AutoDateFormatter`, `ConciseDateFormatter` and `DateFormatter` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html).

The first two automatically figuring out the best format to represent datetime data based on available data and canvas sizes. However, we can use `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter(fmt, tz=None, *, usetex=None)` to modify a tick.

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates   # We use DateFormatter here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=100),
    'value': np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['date'], df['value'])

# Use set_major_formatter and matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter to 
# format the x-axis to show only the date
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Rotate date labels automatically
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: A sample output]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will only change the graph from line to bar and that's it, I've seen how to do this before so thanks for guiding me!